# determine network packet structure

Tags: networking, packet

There is an old program a member of this online community made for everyone to use, but he is no longer around and no longer supports it. I wanted to help the community by extending it's features somewhat. To do that, I need to know how data is sent from it. How can I capture the network traffic it sends, and determine what it's sending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is your friend. Available for UNIX and Windows.

> Wireshark is a network packet analyzer. A network packet analyzer will
>   try to capture network packets and tries to display that packet data
>   as detailed as possible.

[Wireshark User's Guide](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/)

**@Kerrek SB's Tip**: use `tcpdump -s0 -w /tmp/data -i eth3` or so to create the dump file, and analyze it with Wireshark later as an unprivileged user.

Comment: okay, so I have the binary data. How can I determine what the structure is for the data?

Comment: I usually use `tcpdump -s0 -w /tmp/data -i eth3` or so to create the dump file, and only analyze it with Wireshark later as an unprivileged user.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : Great tip! Cheers!

Comment: @MitchWheat are there any resources to help? i'm not really that familiar on how binary data is sent or organized?

Comment: @LordZardeck There really is no substitute for experience. You start out with a blank slate and then pretty quickly start to narrow it down. Is it text? Is it binary? Does it appear to contain length information followed by that many bytes of data? It may help to look at what libraries the program is built with. Does it have an X.509 library? Or a JSON library?

Comment: how can i determine if it contains length information followed by that many bytes? i know it to be binary, and the program written in VB6

Comment: Write a program in VB6; send known strings, ints, doubles etc over the wire capture and analyse...

Comment: lol. you make it sound easy. one more question: is it possible to limit WireShark to only show packets for a specific program?

Comment: It has a rich filtering capability.  Suggest you filter by IP and/or protocol

Comment: yep. figured it out. got lucky, the original programmer delimited his data by using a string naming the data field